nx custom plugin in existing workspace
I'm trying to create a custom nx plugin in an existing workspace. The goal is for this plugin to add an inferred task to projects. I have followed the following steps:
Generate plugin project:
nx add @nx/plugin
npx nx g plugin tooling/my-plugin

I have then added the plugin to nx.json, e.g.
"plugins": [
 {
   "plugin": "@myorg/my-plugin"
 },
 // etc.
]

There's nothing in the plugin itself at the moment, e.g. index.ts looks like this for now:
import { CreateNodesV2 } from '@nx/devkit';

export const createNodesV2: CreateNodesV2 = [
  '*',
  () => {
    console.log('Running createNodesV2');
    return [];
  },
];


When I run nx list I don't see my plugin nor do i see "Running createNodesV2" printed anywhere.
Is there anything else I need to do to actually register this plugin and have it executed.
Thank you.
Edit
I have updated the tooling/my-plugin/package.json, adding an entry for the executors, e.g.
{
  "name": "@myorg/my-plugin",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "type": "commonjs",
  "main": "./src/index.js",
  "typings": "./src/index.d.ts",
  "executors": "./executors.json", // <- ADDED THIS LINE
  "private": true
}

The executors file is essentially empty because I don't want to create a new executor, e.g.
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema"
}

With this change, when I run nx list, my plugin actually does show up in the output, e.g.
NX   Local workspace plugins:

@myorg/my-plugin (graph-extension,project-inference)

So, it looks like the plugin is correctly detected but i don't see any evidence that it attempts to infer tasks.
